# Using elastic ip for amazon's ElasticBeanstalk instance

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ebs

I have a Single-Instance EB environment, with an elastic ip. However, I can't seem to ssh to the current instance using the elastic ip, only the private ip. How do I fix it?

When I try to ssh using the elastic ip, it just hangs.

Answer (score 0):

Your Elastic Beanstalk instance won't have port 22 open by default. Either you have to add a security group that has it open (can also add port 22 to an existing security group that is already used) or you can use the CLI to SSH to your instance.

```
eb ssh
```

It will open the port for you automatically while you are logged in.